# How can I split a string with multiple separators and integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I am trying to split or extract the API GW ID from an AWS Config Rule. The Cloudwatch log provides me with resourceID `arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/64bi74jqe9` I need to extract `64bi74jqe9` to do an update-rest-api call?

I tried doing this but it gives me an error:

```
'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
```

```
arn = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/64bi74jqe9"

a,b,c,d,e,f,api = arn.split(":", "/")
api = int(api)

print(api)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of split should be a count not a second delimeter.

You can make this code work with the following snippet.

```
import re

arn = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/64bi74jqe9"
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,api = re.split(':|\/', arn)
print(api)
```

Comment: correct, I am to trying extract ```64bi74jqe9``` I figured it needed to be an interger because it is seeing the first set of numbers.

Comment: No this would just be a string

Comment: I removed int and still have the error: 

```arn = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/64bi74jqe9"

a,b,c,d,e,f,api = arn.split(":", "/")

print(api)```

Answer (score 0):

If that ID is gonna always have that format then, you can just do

```
arn = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/64bi74jqe9"
id = arn.split('/')[-1]
print(id) # should output 64bi74jqe9
```